# How to write inner join query in JPARepository

Tags: java, mysql, repository, spring-data-jpa, inner-join

I have the following query which runs perfectly in MySQL but it gives an error when I written in repository How can I write inner join query in `JPARepository`?

```
@Query("Select address from Address a inner join Order o ON a.id=o.pickup_address_id where o.customer_id=: customerId  AND a.address LIKE 'C%'")
     Set<Address> findPickupAddress(@Param("customerId") Long customerId);
```

Error : unexpected token: Order near line 1, column 66

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a reserved word. If you can't rename the table you should use it like:

```
@Query("Select address from Address a inner join `Order` o ON ...")
```

Comment: Check my answer :')

Comment: The query in your question is a native sql query and not a jpql!

Answer (score -1):

There is no `ON` in JPQL so the query is updated as :

```
 @Query("Select a from Address a , Order o where a.id=o.pickupAddress AND o.customer.id=:customerId  AND a.address LIKE 'C%'")
     Address findPickupAddress(@Param("customerId") Long customerId);
}
```

Comment: This will generate an outer join not inner!